# '&' symbol got escaped in the url when used with 'window.location'

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

In my view page inside my mvc application, I have something like this

```
@{ 
    var controllerUrl = Url.Content("~/" + ViewBag.NextLink);
    var fullPath = controllerUrl + "?stdId=4044&stdPtId=3052&=5366";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var fullPath =  '@fullPath';
</script>

<div class="marginspace">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Next" onclick="window.location=fullPath;" />
</div>
```

The problem is the when I clicked on the 'Next' button, the url shows

```
http://something?stdId=4044&amp;stdPtId=3052&amp;fid=5366
```

See how the '&' symbol got escaped in the url

My expected url should be

```
http://something?stdId=4044&stdPtId=3052&fid=5366
```

So how can I make sure the url will be properly built without escaping the '&' symbol?

By the way, I have tried with this

```
onclick="window.location=decodeURI(fullPath);"
```

and this

```
onclick="window.location=unescape(fullPath);"
```

and still nothing change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

```
 var fullPath = '@fullPath';
```

Razor `@` will, by default, HTML encode your output.  As `&` is not valid HTML, it converts it to `&amp;`.  This is great as it means you don't need to sanity check all your inputs and can just `@User.CompanyName` (with eg name as "B&Q") will output `B&amp;Q` to be displayed as `B&Q`.

In the occasional place where you want the output to be exactly what as-is without being encoded, you use:

```
var fullPath = '@Html.Raw(fullPath)';
```

and it will output the variable exactly as-is without encoding it first.